# accessing gridLayout grids

Tags: java, swing, awt, jpanel, grid-layout

So I'm using borderLayout panel with a girdLayout for the Center Position, I have added some objects to my gridLayout but latter on I would like to add some more information to the same grids.

```
private JFrame frame;
private JPanel mainPanel;
static private JPanel centerPanel;

public void loadPlayer(Player player){
int count = 1;

 centerPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1,3));

for (Item i: player.getAllItems()){

    JPanel jpI= new JPanel();
    JLabel jlItem= new JLabel(i.getName());
    BorderLayout bl = (BorderLayout) (mainPanel.getLayout()) ;
    jpI.add(jlItem);
    jpI.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLACK));

    centerPanel.add(jpI);
    mainPanel.add(centerPanel,BorderLayout.CENTER);

 }
```

My initial thoughts are to add 3 JPanel properties to my class and append those when need be. Is this a sensible idea? or is there a more efficient/effective way of doing this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What do you mean by "add some more information to the same grids."? Do you mean that you wish to be able to alter the information stored inside of the three JPanels? Or that you want to be able to remove the current JPanels and add new ones as needed?

It seems like you want to update the JPanels stored as the player's information changes. In that case, declare the JPanels outside of the for loop (where you declare your JFrame and main Panel).